# PYTHON: reading list from file

Tags: python, file

i'm storing animals spiecies' names inside a file, one name in a line, and i'd like to read them from file into a list.

1. Why isn't the function "read_from_file()" working?
2. Is there an option to modify the list globally in other way than in function "working_func()"
3. Is the function "func_return()" a proper substitute to the case 2.?

Here's the code:

test_file.txt:
dog
horse
spider

```
from pathlib import Path

def read_from_file(values):
    path = Path('test_file.txt')
    file_contents = path.read_text()
    values = file_contents.split()

def working_func():
    global animals
    path = Path('test_file.txt')
    file_contents = path.read_text()
    animals = file_contents.split()

def func_return():
    path = Path('test_file.txt')
    file_contents = path.read_text()
    values = file_contents.split()
    return values

animals = []

read_from_file(animals)
read_from_file(animals)
print(animals) #[]

working_func()
print(animals) #['dog', 'horse', 'spider']

animals = func_return()
print(animals) #['dog', 'horse', 'spider']
```

i'd like to find out what is the most efficient and common way to do such task

Comment: Why do you call `read_from_file()` twice?

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing the filepath as an argument rather than coding that into the function. Here is one example:

```
import os

test_data_path = "./test_data.txt"

def read_from_file(filepath):
    animals = []
    with open(filepath) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            animals.append(line.strip())
    return animals

animals = read_from_file(test_data_path)
print(animals)
```

Returns:

```
['dog', 'horse', 'spider']
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just don't return anything in `read_from_file()`. It reads from files, stores values ​​in `values`, but when exiting the function, this variable goes out of scope.

Your `working_func()` function uses the `global` keyword, which means
that this variable is in global scope and stores a value in a global variable that can be retrieved from anywhere in your code after calling your function.

`func_return()` returns the value that is assigned to the variable `animals` on line 28, so this means that "animals - is all that func_return() returns".

[More about returns](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/)